# Gradient of constrained sum

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I want to minimise a real-valued cost function for a single-layer perceptron which has a parameter vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^N$.

The cost function is
$$ c(w) = \sum_{\{p: \, y_p \cdot \langle w, x_p \rangle \leq 0\}} y_p \cdot \langle w, x_p \rangle $$
My goal is to find $w \neq 0$ such that minimises $c(w)$ for a fixed set of possible input tuples $\{(x_p,y_p)\}_{p=1}^M$, were $x_p \in \mathbb{R}^N$, $y_p \in \mathbb{R}$.

If I want to find its minimums, I have to compute it's gradient with respect to $w$, but how can I compute it if $w$ appears in the sum's constraint!?

However, since for any given $w$ the set of indexes $p$ for the sum is fixed, I think I can ignore that constraint to compute the gradient and just write:
$$\nabla_w c(w) = \sum_{\{p: \, y_p \cdot  \langle w, x_p \rangle \leq 0\}} y_p \cdot x_p $$
and find the minimum using gradient descent.

I'd like to get some feedback, if this idea works in my problem and/or in general , and maybe some materials (books or links are appreciated!) I can check about this.

This problem is related to [backpropagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) and Rosenblat's Delta Rule, which I should be able to derive from the solution.

Comment: This is a linear programming problem. If $w$ is in the admissible region then yes you can compute the gradient ignoring the constraint. But during the gradient descent, you need to be careful with the case $w$ admissible but $w-\eta \nabla w$ not admissible. This is why we often use some projection of the gradient. https://neos-guide.org/content/gradient-projection-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Not an answer, only a long comment).
I think that your argument is not correct.
Namely, you can write your function as
$$
c(w) = \sum_{p=1}^M \psi_p(w),
\qquad
\psi_p(w) := \min\{0, y_p \langle w, x_p\rangle\}.
$$
At points where $y_p \langle w, x_p\rangle\neq 0$ for every $p$, every $\psi_p$ is differentiable and the gradient of $c$ can be computed by your formula.

On the other hand, if $y_p \langle w, x_p\rangle = 0$ for some $p$, then the corresponding function $\psi_p$ is not differentiable.
Anyway, you can compute the generalized gradient $\partial \psi_p(w)$ and try to work using it.